# S3 and EMR data locality

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

Data locality with MapReduce and HDFS is very important (same thing goes for Spark, HBase). I've been researching about AWS and the two options when deploying the cluster in their cloud:

- EC2
- EMR + S3

The second option seems more appealing for different reasons, where the most interesting is the ability to scale storage and processing separately and to shutdown processing when you don't need it (more correct, to turn it on only when needed). [This](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/31/top-5-reasons-for-choosing-s3-over-hdfs.html?utm_campaign=Company%20Blog&utm_content=55155959&utm_medium=social&utm_source=linkedin) is an example explaining the advantages of using S3.

What bugs me is the issue of data locality. If the data is stored in S3 it will need to be pulled to HDFS every time a job is run. My question is - how big can this issue be, and is it still worth of it?

What comforts me is the fact that I'll be pulling the data only the first time and then all the next jobs will have the intermediate results locally.

I'm hopping for an answer from some person having practical experience with this. Thank you.

Comment: Perfectly good question, not subjective, closed for no good reason.

Comment: Seriously! Why this question is closed as opinion-based???!!!!!!

Answer (score 6):

EMR does not pull data from S3 to HDFS. It uses its own implementation of HDFS support on S3 (as if you are operating on an actual HDFS). https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-fs.html

As for data locality, S3 is `RACK_LOCAL` to EMR spark clusters.

Comment: this makes total sense however there is literally no documentation from aws confirming s3 data locality for emr spark is ```RACK_LOCAL``` ... have you found any?

Answer (score 1):

As per the source mentioned below, EMR+S3 with EMRFS doesn't maintain data locality and is not suitable for analytics processing based on tools such as SQL. RedShift is the right choice for such use cases where compute and data are at one place. Please refer to 39:00 to 42:00 in the below link:

https://youtu.be/08G9NfDETVE

This is also mentioned in https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/31/top-5-reasons-for-choosing-s3-over-hdfs.html. Please refer to the performance per dollar section.

To check how EMR works with S3 please refer to Programming elastic map reduce book by KEVIN SCHMIDT & CHRISTOPHER PHILLIPS(Chapter 1 Amazon Elastic MapReduce Versus Traditional Hadoop Installs section).