# EMR + S3: how RACK_LOCAL is achieved

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

AFAIK, EMR is highly optimized for reading/writing from/to S3 & has RACK_LOCAL data locality when reading from S3. For me that means they are always within the same availability zone (AZ). In other hand, S3 doesn't have AZs.

*How is that possible to have RACK_LOCAL to the same S3 bucket no matter at which AZ your EMR is deployed?*

Answer (score 1):

RACK_LOCAL implies S3 and EMR are within the same datacenter, whereas an AZ is a collection of datacenters. This makes understanding how RACK_LOCAL is possible even harder.

From the following documentation page, it looks like this locality is achived using EMRFS' "consistent view": https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emrfs-files-tracked.html

Possible duplicate of: [S3 and EMR data locality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44304104/s3-and-emr-data-locality)

Comment: it isn't a duplicate, referenced answer is about saying that EMR & S3 are RACK_LOCAL. While my question is asking how that is possible

Comment: thank you for adding more details. Still I can't understand how RACK_LOCAL is possible. RACK_LOCAL is something that is related to hardware config while EMRFS Consistent View is just a metadata persisted on write operations. I can suppose that EMRFS always writes to the same RACK where EC2 are located, but how about reads? Again that can mean that the same S3 bucket is stored at different RACKs.

Comment: Ah you're right on the reference, my mistake. You're right in that it is metadata, but I assume under the hood, the operation is something similar to how RedShift Spectrum provides RedShift with added capabilities in interating with S3. There does not seem to be any plain answer for RACK_LOCAL since locality is more of a Spark item than it is an EMR feature. I feel the scope of asking "How does X work on AWS" would require you to know how the service is structured under the hood.

Comment: unfortunatelly I can't ask AWS Support since due my plan I have no permission to create technical ticket.
One more word about metadata - at the moment of EMR is starting it doesn't know from which bucket it would read data. So metadata shouldn't help: suppose you re-create EMR and already have few TBs of S3 data

Answer (score 0):

As per the source mentioned below, EMR+S3 with EMRFS doesn't maintain data locality and is not suitable for analytics processing based on tools such as SQL. RedShift is the right choice for such use cases where compute and data are at one place. Please refer to 39:00 to 42:00 in the below link:

https://youtu.be/08G9NfDETVE

This is also mentioned in https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/31/top-5-reasons-for-choosing-s3-over-hdfs.html. Please refer to the performance per dollar section.

To check how EMR works with S3 please refer to Programming elastic map reduce book by KEVIN SCHMIDT & CHRISTOPHER PHILLIPS(Chapter 1 Amazon Elastic MapReduce Versus Traditional Hadoop Installs section).